# Antd table incorrect sorting on pagination

Tags: reactjs, antd

I have a Antd table. it displays correctly. sorted by date in descending order. But when I go to the second page of the table, I see the same data, but sorted in ascending order. I return to the first page and the data is sorted in ascending order.
sorting happens on the client side

1page:
[image]

2page:
[image]

1page again:
[image]

Comment: Please give more information (in code fences ) about how the Ant Design table component is being rendered. You just posted three images!